# Databricks error while creating a permanent table: IllegalArgumentException: Path must be absolute: circuits

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I am trying to create a permanent table in Databricks (dbfs) by importing a csv file. I am able to create the temporary table but when I try to create the permanent table, I get get this error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Path must be absolute: circuits
```

here's the code snippet I am using:

```
df.write.format("parquet").saveAsTable("circuits")
```

- `df` -> dataframe
- `circuits` -> name I want to give to the table

the db I want this table to live in is "default" and I have tried default.circuits as well but that gives the same error.

Comment: can you show `show create table circuits` ? How this table was created

Comment: Thanks for checking my question Alex. Stupid question - do I need to create the table first using a create statement? Doesn't the function 'saveAsTable' do it for you? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable.html

Comment: No, it should work out of the box... I run similar command today, and everything worked just fine without any additional tuning

Comment: What was the fix for this? It is unclear. Also, @RaviDawar the link in your comment does not work now.